# Not able to click the Link Status in The UI

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I  am not able to click the following Status link. I have tried below code :

```
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Status")).click();
```

But error coming as

```
 org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:{"method":"link text","selector":"Status"}
 Command duration or timeout: 30.49 seconds
 For documentation on this error, please visit:   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html.
```

I have copied the html code and highlighted the code with stars where i have click.Plesae help me to click status link

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar ng-scope" ng-controller="navigationController" ng-include="'assets/partials/navigation.html'">
<input id="show-menu" class="ng-scope" type="checkbox" role="button">
<ul id="menu" class="ng-scope">
<div class="navigation">
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
<li id="environment">
<a href="#/environment" ng-class="getClass('/environment')">
<span class="leftside glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>
<h4>Environment </h4>
</a>
</li>
<li id="status">
**<a class="alignleft" href="#/status" ng-class="getClass('/status')">Status</a>**
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: html code is missing

Comment: @ bharath karanth : Please upload HTML code snippet and your implementation in your Question.

Comment: <a href="#/status" ng-class="getClass('/status')" class="alignleft">Status</a>

Comment: Here is my Html code snippet .Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Xpath in order to click the link:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="status"]/a")).click();
```

Comment: Hi I tried by using Xpath      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='status']/a")).click();  but still error is coming as Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='status']/a"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Is the element exposed? Make sure it is visible

Comment: How we cam make sure that element is visible.

Comment: Do you need to click other elements in order to be able to see the link you want to click on? If that is the case then selenium is unable to locate that element.

Comment: No i don't want to click other element .I just wanted to click on link name status.

Comment: @bharathkaranth : what he meant was, whether the **link "status"** is **directly present on the webpage** or **do you have to click on any other element, so that it becomes visible**? Like in this image, where **you've to click on "Drop" button first** to access its options: "Yes" or "Yuuuup!" or "Weeeeee!" : [http://thedesignwork.thedesignwork.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Web-Page-Menu-Design-16.png](http://thedesignwork.thedesignwork.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Web-Page-Menu-Design-16.png)

Comment: Yes the link Status is directly present on the webpage.I have tried Xpath and link Text , and  driver.findElement(by.Css("#status > a")).click();.But it is not clicking.Please help me

Comment: Hi Any update on this issue? Please help me to click status link

Comment: Hi, I tried clicking the link on the html you provided and it worked. Could you  provide the full html or is this website is public so we can see it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use css selector instead of xpaths or smth else (this code will find element with 'statis' id and first a child in it).

```
driver.findElement(by.Css("#status > a")).click();
```

Comment: Updated. BTW i don't think that this code needs any explanation. Any person can understand that this code just uses css for searching elements.